# Navigation drawer change to rtl programmatically

Tags: android, right-to-left, navigation-drawer

I want to change language and layout/text orientation in my app programmatically.
But navigation drawer doesn't change it's items.

Is it possible?

Comment: By changing languange and layout/text orientation, do you mean you want to read it from database instead of hard code it in the application?

Answer (score 0):

1)First You have to define  android:supportsRtl="true" this line in your application tag in manifest.

and check this link - https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Comment: That's a good article, I know this, but this doesn't answer my question. Question is about change languale on-the-fly and change drawer items accordingly.